Is the isomorphism between $\mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{G}$ and the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $\mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{G}$ bijective?
On page 35 of the review of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces by Muandet et al. (1), the authors write that

Is this isomorphism bijective? How can we show this? I know it is injective by the fact it is an isometry.
In ([2]), the author defines two more isomorphisms which are shown to be bijective but they use physics notation that I am not at all familiar with.
References
(1) - Kernel Mean Embedding of Distributions: A Review and Beyond (Muandet, K., Fukumizu, K., Sriperumbudur, B.)
([2]) - Operator Isomorphisms on Hilbert Space Tensor Products (Stan Gudder)

Let $T \in \mathrm{HS}(\mathcal H, \mathcal G)$. Let $\{ \phi_a \}_a$ and $\{ \varphi_b \}_b$ be orthonormal bases of $\mathcal H$ and $\mathcal G$ respectively. For each pair $(a,b)$ define $t_{a,b} = \left< T\phi_a, \varphi_b \right>_\mathcal G$. Since $T$ is HS, we have that
$$\sum_{a,b}t_{a,b}^2 < \infty.$$
Therefore
$$t:= \sum_{a,b} t_{a,b}\ \phi_a \otimes \varphi_b$$
is a well-defined element of $\mathcal H \otimes \mathcal G$. It remains to show that $t$ maps to $T$ under the isometry $(3.15)$, which I leave as an exercise.

Thanks, this is very helpful!
Letting $F: \mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{G} \to \text{HS}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{G})$ be our isometry, I have shown that for $T^\prime := F(t)$ we have $\Vert T^\prime \Vert_{\text{HS}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{G})} = \Vert T\Vert_{\text{HS}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{G})}$. I now think I have to use our isometry to conclude these are the same operators, but I am not sure. Am I along the right lines?

Thank you very much Wei for your answer, I believe this is the rest of the argument to ensure the isometry is surjective.
Let $F: \mathcal{H} \otimes \mathcal{G} \to \text{HS}(\mathcal{H}, \mathcal{G})$ be our isometry, and define $T^\prime := F(t)$ where $t$ is defined as in Wei's answer. Then we have
\begin{align}
T^\prime h = \sum_{a, b} t_{a,b}\langle h, \phi_a \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \psi_b
\end{align}
Now, in order to show $T^\prime = T$, it is equivalent to prove that $\langle T^\prime \phi_c, \psi_d \rangle_{\mathcal{G}} = \langle T \phi_c, \psi_d \rangle_{\mathcal{G}}$ for all $c, d$:
\begin{align}
\langle T^\prime \phi_c, \psi_d \rangle_{\mathcal{G}} &= \left\langle \sum_{a, b} t_{a,b} \langle \phi_c, \phi_a \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \psi_b, \psi_d \right\rangle_{\mathcal{G}}\\
&= \sum_{a, b} \langle T\phi_a, \psi_b \rangle_{\mathcal{G}} \langle \phi_c, \phi_a \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} \langle  \psi_b, \psi_d \rangle_{\mathcal{G}}\\
&= \langle T\phi_c, \psi_d \rangle_{\mathcal{G}}
\end{align}
due to the orthogonality of the bases $\{ \phi_a \}, \{ \psi_b \}$.
